# InventorySystem List of Items and their subclass Permanents Bug

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, subclass

Hey I could need some help with my inventory system. It's very simplistic - i guess - however i got some problems and I couldn't find a solution online.

//! Edited minimal to the best of my knowledge

My task from university is to do a system that contains sub-classes. It worked fine till I added the sub-classes.. Apparently the items are created and added to the inventory at start but somehow the child part and in-fact the entire item seems to be overwritten at some point. My guess is that the List of items will cause problems later on when the sub-class of permanents are added.

Anyway I just started out and I can't find the problem.

Any help would be appreciated - or point me into the right direction where I could read up on the given problem.

Cheers and thanks in advance!

ItemDatabase

```
public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    void Start ()
    {
        items.Add(new Permanent(0, "Iron Armor", "The armor has seen battle.", 0, Item.ItemType.Permanent, 110, 20000, 6640, 600, 100, true, "Torso", 5, -5, 10, 50));
        items.Add(new Consumable(139, "Healing Potion", "Brew that will restore health.", 1, Item.ItemType.Consumable, 30, 800, 720, 100, 100, 1, 3, 50, 0, 0, 0));
        items.Add(new Permanent(376, "Bronze Sword", "The sword is made with poor quality bronze.", 0, Item.ItemType.Permanent, 5, 1480, 820, 480, 100, true, "Hand", 5, -5, 10, 50));
        items.Add(new Permanent(24, "Gladiator Helmet", "This helmet can kick ass!", 0, Item.ItemType.Permanent, 110, 20000, 6640, 500, 200, true, "Head", 5, -5, 10, 50));

    }
}
```

Inventory

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int slotsX, SlotsY;
    public GUISkin skin;
    public List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
    public List<Item> slots = new List<Item>();
    private ItemDatabase database;
    private bool showInventory;
    private bool showTooltip;
    public string tooltip;

    private bool draggingItem;
    private Item draggedItem;
    private int prevIndex;

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (slotsX * SlotsY); i++)
        {
            slots.Add(new Item());
            inventory.Add(new Item());
        }

        database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();

        AddItem(0);
        AddItem(0);
        AddItem(139);
        AddItem(376);
        AddItem(24);

    }

    void AddItem(int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inventory[i].itemName == null)
            {
                for (int j =0; j < database.items.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (database.items[j].itemID == id)
                    {
                        inventory[i] = database.items[j];
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Item

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int itemID;
    public string itemName;
    public string itemDesc;
    public int itemTypeInt;
    public ItemType itemType;
    public Texture2D itemIcon;
    public int itemValue;
    public float itemWeight;
    public int itemVolume;
    public int itemSturdiness;
    public int itemHealth;

    public string cpermanent = "#ffff66";
    public string cconsumable = "#00ffff";
    public string cmiscellaneous = "#ff00ff";
    public string cdefault = "#ffffff";

    public enum ItemType
    {
        Permanent,
        Consumable,
        Miscellaneous,
    }

    public Item(int id, string name, string desc, int typeint, ItemType type, int value, float weight, int volume, int sturdiness, int health)
    {
        itemID = id;
        itemName = name;
        itemDesc = desc;
        itemTypeInt = typeint;
        itemType = type;
        itemIcon = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Item Icons/" + id);
        itemValue = value;
        itemWeight = weight;
        itemVolume = volume;
        itemSturdiness = sturdiness;
        itemHealth = health;
    }

    public Item()
    {
        itemID = -1;
    }
}
```

Permanent

```
public class Permanent : Item
{
    public bool pequipment;
    public string pequipmentslot;
    public int pstre;
    public int pagil;
    public int pinte;
    public int pwisd;
    public Permanent(int id, string name, string desc, int typeint, ItemType type, int value, float weight, int volume, int sturdiness, int health, bool equipment, string equipmentslot, int stre, int agil, int intl, int wisd) : base(id, name, desc, typeint, type,  value, weight, volume, sturdiness, health)
    {
        bool pequipment = equipment;
        string pequipmentslot = equipmentslot;
        int pstre = stre;
        int pagil = agil;
        int pinte = intl;
        int pwisd = wisd;
    }

}
```

Consumable

```
public class Consumable : Item
{
    public int ccharges;
    public int cmaxcharges;
    public int cstre;
    public int cagil;
    public int cinte;
    public int cwisd;
    public Consumable(int id, string name, string desc, int typeint, ItemType type, int value, float weight, int volume, int sturdiness, int health, int charges, int maxcharges, int stre, int agil, int intl, int wisd) : base(id, name, desc, typeint, type, value, weight, volume, sturdiness, health)
    {
        int ccharges = charges;
        int cmaxcharges = maxcharges;
        int cstre = stre;
        int cagil = agil;
        int cinte = intl;
        int cwisd = wisd;
    }
}
```

Miscellaneous

```
public class Miscellaneous : Item
{
    public bool mquest;

    public Miscellaneous(int id, string name, string desc, int typeint, ItemType type, int value, float weight, int volume, int sturdiness, int health, bool quest) : base(id, name, desc, typeint, type, value, weight, volume, sturdiness, health)
    {
        bool mquest = quest;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should absolutely trim this down. - [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Run it line-by-line in the debugger, inspecting variables to see where it goes wrong.  Debugging by just reading code is orders of magnitude more difficult that observing problems in-the-wild.